# C++ Access derived class member from base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, derived-class

If I allocate an object of a class `Derived` (with a base class of `Base`), and store a pointer to that object in a variable that points to the base class, how can I access the members of the `Derived` class?

Here's an example:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    int base_int;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    int derived_int;
};

Base* basepointer = new Derived();
basepointer-> //Access derived_int here, is it possible? If so, then how?
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, you cannot access `derived_int` because `derived_int` is part of `Derived`, while `basepointer` is a pointer to `Base`.

You can do it the other way round though:

```
Derived* derivedpointer = new Derived;
derivedpointer->base_int; // You can access this just fine
```

Derived classes inherit the members of the base class, not the other way around.

However, if your `basepointer` was pointing to an instance of `Derived` then you could access it through a cast:

```
Base* basepointer = new Derived;
static_cast<Derived*>(basepointer)->derived_int; // Can now access, because we have a derived pointer
```

Note that you'll need to change your inheritance to `public` first:

```
class Derived : public Base
```

Comment: shouldn't he use dynamic_cast instead of static_cast?

Comment: That depends whether or not he knows that it is a `Derived` or not. If you are 100% sure (as we are here) then `static_cast` is fine.

Comment: doesn't everyone mean reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast? I'm pretty sure static_cast won't compile.

Comment: @Balk No, `static_cast` is the correct thing here. `reinterpret_cast` would compile, but it does the wrong thing in many cases. `reinterpret_cast` does not change the address stored in the pointer, it just reinterprets it. However, `static_cast` sometimes needs to offset the pointer (e.g. if `Derived` inherited from multiple bases)

Comment: Firstly you can't use dynami_cast unless you are dealing with polymorphic classes. This class(es) doesn't have any member functions to really add virtual behavior to it. static_cast is the best thing to do in the given scenario.

Answer (score 15):

You're dancing on a minefield here. The base class can never know that it's actually an instance of the derived. The safest way to do that would be to introduce a virtual function in the base:

```
class Base 
{ 
protected:
 virtual int &GetInt()
 {
  //Die horribly
 }

public: 
 int base_int; 
}; 

class Derived : Base 
{ 
  int &GetInt()
  {
    return derived_int;
  }
public: 
int derived_int 
}; 

basepointer->GetInt() = 0;
```

If `basepointer` points as something other that a `Derived`, your program will die horribly, which is the intended result.

Alternatively, you can use `dynamic_cast<Derived>(basepointer)`. But you need at least one virtual function in the `Base` for that, and be prepared to encounter a zero.

The `static_cast<>`, like some suggest, is a sure way to shoot yourself in the foot. Don't contribute to the vast cache of "unsafety of the C language family" horror stories.

Comment: "Alternatively, you can use dynamic_cast(basepointer). But you need at least one virtual function in the Base for that, and be prepared to encounter a zero." --> Good Point Seva.Liked It :)

Comment: Using `static_cast` is not a way to shoot yourself in the foot. I think you're confusing it with C's explicit cast notation `(T)x`. `static_cast` on the other hand is type safe, but `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer if it can't convert while `static_cast` will issue a compiler error.

Answer (score 10):

you can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

you basically use the derived class in the template for the base class

Answer (score 8):

It is possible by letting the base class know the type of derived class. This can be done by making the base class a template of derived type. This C++ idiom is called [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Knowing the derived class, the base class pointer can be static-casted to a pointer to derived type.

```
template<typename DerivedT>
class Base
{
public:
    int accessDerivedField()
    {
        auto derived = static_cast<DerivedT*>(this);
        return derived->field;
    }
};


class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    int field;
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = new Derived;
    obj->accessDerivedField();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//if you know what derived class you are going to use

Derived* derivedpointer = dynamic_cast < Derived * > basepointer;

//then you can access derived class using derivedpointer