# Function return different types

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, covariant-return-types

Given a Base struct and Derived Structs, I would like to write a method that can return any of them depending on some input, for example on an int, string etc.

Thus far I tried out various code snippets, like the following:

```
struct Base {
    std::string name = "Base";
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
    std::string name = "Derived1";
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
    std::string name = "Derived2";
};

template<class T>
T string_to_struct(std::string s) {
    if(s== "Derived1") {
        return Derived1();
    } else if(s == "Derived2") {
        return Derived2();
    } else {
        return Base();
    }
}
```

In main I call the function:

```
void test2() {
    std::string s = "Derived1";
    auto bb = string_to_struct<Base>(s);
    std::cout << bb.name << std::endl;
}
```

Now I would expect to print "Derived1" if s is matches "Derived1", "Derived2"if it equals "Derived2" and so on. Above code however, does not work and string_to_struct returns in any case an instance of "Base". How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't access `name` directly. Use a virtual method.

Comment: How does accessing name help me? Name is not relevant.

Comment: Can you use const char* instead string?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka What would that accomplish?

Comment: @MaxLanghof, I was thinking about constexprs. Looks like `name` field is compile time constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best case in above scenario would be to use static_cast. The corresponding code snippet would then look like:

```
Base* string_to_struct7(std::string s) {
    if(s== "Derived1") {
        return new Derived1();
    } else if(s == "Derived2") {
        return new Derived2();
    } else {
        return new Base();
    }
```

and then for further processing:

```
auto t = string_to_struct7(s);
auto bb7 = static_cast<Derived1*>(t);
std::cout << bb7->name<< std::endl;
```

which is exactly, what I want to have. Derived class members can now be addressed directly.

Max Langhof's answer is of course also valid. Using simply Java like getter methods works, but has the drawback they have to be defined in every class for every class member, which can get out of hand quickly.

More information can be also found here: [C++ Access derived class member from base class pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436125/c-access-derived-class-member-from-base-class-pointer)

EDIT: A third approach would be to use a wrapper object inside the Derived Classes and a virtual getter method. Currently I can't think of a drawback - apart from being ugly.

Answer (score 4):

`string_to_struct` always returns a `Base` by value (because you asked for that). Since the static type of `bb` is a `Base`, `bb.name` always refers to `Base::name`. And since you return by value, the dynamic type of `bb` will also always be `Base`.

You would need to do two things to get what you want:

1. Do not return polymorphic objects by `Base` value. If they are created in the function, the best return value would be a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. Reason: You need references or pointers for polymorphy to work.
2. Do not use accesses that rely on the *static type* of the object, such as `.name`. You want to use the *dynamic type* of `bb`, which is easiest to do with a virtual method such as:

   ```
   virtual std::string getName() const
   ```

   That is also a cleaner solution than relying on the (very brittle) name hiding.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this issue is known as *object slicing*.